# Freeswitch - Calling out via mod_curl using the dialplan

Tags: curl, freeswitch

I am trying to replicate an API service we use on another switch which requires the passing of basic call information (Caller No and Callee numbers) to a webpage using the mod_curl action.

The code I have is this , in the default inbound dialplan:

```
 <action application="curl" data="http://web.test.net/fs.php post id=${new}" inline="true"/>
```

If I paste the curl request from within FS_CLI it does paste information,so I know curl is enabled and working on the server.  However, If I dial the number associated with the dialplan nothing happens - I cant even see that FS has tried to run the action.

Can anyone advise on how to call out to a URL passing some variables from within the dialplan.  I realise I could build an event listener, but thats overkill for what Im trying to achieve.

Full code below:

```
<include>
  <extension name="sip-inbound">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(xxxx594xxxx)$">
        <action application="set" data="domain_name=$${domain}"/>
        <action application="curl" data="http://web.test.net/fs.php post id=${new}" inline="true"/>
      <action application="bridge" data="1000 XML default"/>
    </condition>
  </extension>
</include>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you reloadxml after saving? Can you paste a log of the call somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
        <action application="system" data="/bin/curl http://web.test.net/fs.php post id=${new}" inline="true"/>
```

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_system